# custom uitableview section design

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I would like to have a custom section design for my app.

The particular case would be to have a text displayed on the left of the section elements.

Could someone help? i've attached a image to better explain what i mean.

[image: custom section design]

**UPDATE 1**

Let me elaborate: I would like to have a uitableview with N number of sections, each with variable number of elements per section. For each section, i would like to have a description on the left of the rows. The scroll show act as in any other uitableview.

Comment: It's not much clear. What about more rows for section? And what about scroll?

Comment: @LucaD what do you mean? Let me elaborate: I would like to have a uitableview with N number of sections, each with variable number of elements per section. For each section, i would like to have a description on the left of the rows.

Comment: show your code also.

Comment: @SumitGarg right now, i have a tipical uitableview, the code is not specific. I have updated my question with more info.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a `UICollectionView` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a table view, in each cell in the left side add a label and on the right side add a new tableview.